# Determinant of a $3 \times 3$ matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

I have a matrix of order $3 \times 3$. When I take its determinant it give 1700 from all the rows and columns except row 2. I don`t know whats going on

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&20&0\\0&0&10\\10&30&20\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: I am not sure, whether my answer hits your intent. Please tell me, if this is not the case.

Comment: Any reference for that sign concept you gave? Cause  I think alternate signs works in determinant case

Comment: Thanks for the answer any reference would be great sir

Comment: Surely any text explaining determinants explains the checkerboard sign scheme also?

Comment: @AsadJivani: When you ask a "what am I doing wrong?" type question, it is vitally important to **actually show what you're doing** in the question. When, as here, you're just saying that you're not getting the right result, nobody can tell you what your mistake is. That's only possible if you reveal which wrong result you get and how you get it.

Comment: @HenningMakholm I apologize for it Sir. You are Right . . I could have asked this question in better way.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I believe a proper documented thing would be more helpful for me. By the way this is also enough

Comment: @Peter What is the sign scheme in expanding through column is it same or you just alter the sign as you advances in a particular column use for expansion?

Comment: @AsadJivani: Apologizing without actually fixing the question is useless. On the other hand, fixing your question without apologizing would have given you a chance of getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\pmatrix{1&20&0\\0&0&10\\10&30&20}$$

If you use the second row, you get $(-10) \cdot (30-200)=(-10)\cdot (-170)=1700$

Note that the sign-scheme is

$+\ -\ +$

$-\ +\ -$

$+\ -\ +$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left| \begin{array}{ccc} 1&20&0\\ 0&0&10\\ 10&30&20\\\end{array} \right|$$
$$=-0\cdot\left|\begin{array}{cc}20 & 0\\30&20\end{array}\right|
+0\cdot\left|\begin{array}{cc}1 & 0\\10&20\end{array}\right|
-10\cdot\left|\begin{array}{cc} 1 & 20\\10&30\end{array}\right|$$
$$=-0 + 0 -10(1\cdot30-20\cdot10)$$
$$=-10\cdot(30-200) = -10\cdot(-170)$$
$$=+1700$$